# Can you pack multiple Tkinter widgets at a time rather than packing them individually?

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

You create an initial root window and then multiple widgets (such as Labels, Buttons, Events).

You have to pack each one of them and can do it in several ways that I'm aware of.

```
Button(root, text="Button1", command=something).pack()
```

or

```
btn1 = Button(root, text="Button1", command=something)
btn1.pack()
```

Is it possible to pack multiple widgets that are assigned to "root" in one swoop **without** using a for loop and **explicitly naming the items**, like this:

```
for item in [btn1, btn2, label1, label2]:
    item.pack()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `root.children` to get all the buttons and labels added to that parent element and then call the `pack` function for those. `children` is a dictionary, mapping IDs to actual elements.

```
root = Tk()

label1  = Label(root, text="label1")
button1 = Button(root, text="button1")
label2  = Label(root, text="label2")
button2 = Button(root, text="button2")

for c in sorted(root.children):
    root.children[c].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will `pack` all those buttons and labels underneath each other, from top to bottom, in the same order as they where added to the parent element (due to `sorted`). Note, however, that the usefulness of this is rather limited, since normally you'd not just place all your widgets in one column.

Comment: In Python 3.12, I don't need to use `sorted(root.children)` because that's actually in reverse order.