# Python tkinter - frame within frame causing issues

Tags: python

I am creating a table in python GUI using the pack method where students can enter their name by "requesting" help.

Below is a modified and simplified version of my code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(object):
def __init__(self, master):
    self._master = master
    master.title = 'Table'
    master.geometry('600x600')
    frame = tk.Frame(master).pack()
    button = tk.Button(frame, text="Ask for help", 
                        command=self.request_help)
    button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    # frame for hashtag
    self._hashtagframe = tk.Frame(frame)
    self._hashtagframe.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    # frame for Names
    self._nameframe = tk.Frame(frame)
    self._nameframe.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    # frame for buttons
    self._timeframe = tk.Frame(frame).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

def request_help(self):
    name = "BOB" # they enter some name
    num = "number" # they are some number
    namelabel=tk.Label(self._nameframe, text=name).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    numlabel=tk.Label(self._hashtagframe, text=num).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    student_timeframe = tk.Frame(self._timeframe).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    redbutton = tk.Button(student_timeframe, command=blah1)
    redbutton.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    greenbutton= tk.Button(student_timeframe, command=blah2)
    greenbutton.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

When a student enters their name, in the button frame, a red and green button must appear. I am attempting to get this all in the same 'row' by creating a frame to put those 2 buttons in. However, when I run this code, the two buttons are veering way off to the side.

I have tried altering everything yet the text and 2 buttons keep veering over to the right. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Alternativ: [Can you pack multiple Tkinter widgets at a time rather than packing them individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25329347/7414759)

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
student_timeframe = tk.Frame(self._timeframe).pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W, expand=True)
```

This stores the return value of `pack()` in `student_timeframe`, which is `None`.
Therefore, you don't actually pack your `timelabel`, `redbutton` and `greenbutton` in this frame, because you pass `None` as their parent, which makes it default to the root window.

Split up the line like

```
student_timeframe = tk.Frame(self._timeframe)
student_timeframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W, expand=True)
```

so that `student_timeframe` actually holds a reference to the Frame.

Comment: You're welcome. Since this is your first question, you might might be interested in reading the ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) page from the Help Center.